# Trouble with "IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN"

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm building a Flask Application with SQLAlchemy for query and SQL Server for Database Storage. Recently I noticed in SQL Server Activity Monitor there are a lot of open sessions look like this:

[image: capture]

I did some search and was not able to find any reason. I wonder if anyone know what's causing this issue?

Note: Some background, requests managed directly under Flask context seem to be ok(So clicking around on the website and running query does not cause this). This happens only when I run backend Celery Task.

Is it possible caused by my code structure?

This is how I defined session connection(use scoped_session):

```
engine = create_engine('connection string here')
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening in your application is , you have written some code which does something like ....

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

 -- Some code here 


IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
 BEGIN
   COMMIT TRANSACTION;
 END
```

but what about if the code after you have opened a transaction has not affected any rows?

You have not COMMITTED it, which makes sense since there is no change to commit but you have left an OPEN TRANSACTION.

You code should look something this...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

 -- Some code here 


IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
 BEGIN
   COMMIT TRANSACTION;
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
 END
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any code like this , either it's done within ORM model, or just some straight forward `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries.. And I've checked all `UPDATE` are committed use `db_session.commit()` and `SELECT` query are parsed using `fetchall()`.

Comment: If you dont have any code like this, then SQL Server Activity Monitor must be lying to you :)

Comment: I have a very similar task, but instead of using celery to schedule task, I used Windows Scheduled Task, which is not causing this issue. Strange...Probably need to dig a little more..